# How to dynamically determine objects based on some uniqueness?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, sensor, opencv, rfid

As the title states I looking for a way to (detect and then) determine a object within some range. The object will be forklift or "train" in the factory. Main goal is to provide some GUI from which it'll be possible to see where was the specific forklift or "train". There will be about 25 places in which I want to put Raspberry to detect those objects (forklifts and "trains"), determine what is the Id of this object it (e.g forklift with Id equals to 1, but I don't have to distinguish between forklift and "train", I care only about Id or something similiar which will be then send to some backend).

After some research on the Internet I have two possible solutions:

- using barcodes and reading their content (Id) using OpenCV,
- using RFID, but I couldn't find anything with larger distance with this technology

I know that this is not forum for  "looking for complete solution with implementation", I only ask you for advices, technologies than can be used, feedback and maybe your experience with similiar problem. But code will be greatly appreciate if you done something similiar before.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider placing bluetooth beacons on each forklift or train. As you probably know, the Raspberry Pi Zero W has a built-in Bluetooth adapter which makes it capable of picking up a signal from a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) beacon.

The advantage to this approach is that it would probably be effective at a further distance and would not require you to purchase a camera module for each Pi.

The downside is that you would have to purchase a Bluetooth beacon for each object you wish to track and replace the batteries every 1-2 years.

If you go with this approach, I recommend checking out this good comparison of Bluetooth beacon hardware: https://www.aislelabs.com/reports/beacon-guide/